# How to create Add-Ins for Skype

Tags: vsto, skype

I have requirement to create an Add-In for Skype. We found that the Skype Add-Ins is in Developer Preview. [Skype Add-In](https://dev.skype.com/addins)

How can i create an app for Skype and how can i integrate it with Skype as Add-In? Anyone knows about the Skype Add-Ins? Any links to create Apps/Add-Ins for Skype?
Is it possible to develop VSTO add-ins for Skype? There are multiple articles on the internet that talk about creating Add-ins for other office products like Outlook, Word, Excel etc., but none for Skype. Could someone point me to some help content for developing add-ins for Skype?

Comment: It's virtually impossible that Skype uses VSTO, that is an Office API, and Skype was not part of MS's portfolio until recently.

Comment: @Chris, Thanks, but the Skype says that the Add-Ins are in Preview. You can find that here https://dev.skype.com/addins.

Comment: These are not exactly a VSTO. You can check out here. https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34728/what-are-add-ins-and-how-do-i-use-them-in-skype-on-mobile

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Microsoft has been using the term add-in very loosely throughout its Office product line to describe very different technologies. In the link you provide, they are referring and alluding to a few different technologies:

**Skype Developer Platform & Desktop APIs**

The Skype Developer Platform includes APIs for integrating Skype with websites and, via its Desktop API, desktop applications. As of this writing the Desktop APIs still refer to Skype as Lync -- Skype's previous name. These APIs are for the type of integrations typically associated with VSTO and Office.js in other Office applications. The SDKs can be found here:

[Skype Developer Platform SDKs](https://dev.office.com/Skype/sdks)

**Skype for Business Bot Framework**

Skype can be integrated with the Microsoft Bot Framework to create automation and guided experiences.

[Skype for Business Bot Framework Introduction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview)

[Azure Bot Service Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

**Skype App SDK**

Lastly, there are also the SDKs to use Skype in Android and/or IOS apps.

[Skype App SDK Getting Started Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/gettingstarted)